# Unable to perform click on Vuetify vSwitch when testing with Jest

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, vuetify.js

I am currently writing tests for a Vue Component which implements a Vuetify Switch. As part of the testing I want to check the functionality of the vuetify switch. I am having troubling triggering a click on the switch to then verify that the switches value has changed (and once I have done that I will verify that the value bound to the switch has changed as well)

I have looked at the API docs for Vuetify and there are no methods to directly set the state of a Vuetify switch which is bewildering in my opinion. Because of this I am trying to perform a click on the VSwitch component using `wrapper.find().trigger('click')` but this isn't changing the switch value, leading me to believe the click isn't doing anything at all.

Below are two tests

- the first checks that the switch has the correct state on creation, which is passing
- The second tries to perform a click event and check that the state has changed, which is failing

Any help in resolving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

**switch.vue**

```js
<template>

    <v-row>
        <v-col>
            <label class="label-text" :for="`${fieldLabel}`">{{labelText}}</label>
            <v-row>
                <label class="left-label">{{toggleLeftText}}</label>
                <v-switch
                        :id="`${fieldLabel}`"
                        v-model="toggleState"
                        class="ma-0 pa-0"
                        :data-qa="`${fieldLabel}Checkbox`"
                >
                </v-switch>
                <label class="right-label">{{toggleRightText}}</label>
            </v-row>
            <!--Hidden input field includes switch value in form when submitted-->
            <input type="hidden" :value="toggleState" :name="`${fieldLabel}`">
        </v-col>
    </v-row>


</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "Switch",
        props: {
            fieldLabel: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            labelText: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            toggleLeftText: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            toggleRightText: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            toggleValue: {
                type: Boolean,
                required: true
            },

        },

        data: function () {
            return {
                toggleState: this.toggleValue
            }
        }

    }
</script>
```

**switch.spec.js**

```js
describe('Switch', () => {

    const toggleState = true;

    const localVue = createLocalVue();
    localVue.use(Vuetify, {
        components: {
            VRow,
            VCol,
            VSwitch,
            InputError
        }
    });

    const wrapperFactory = () => {
        return shallowMount(Switch, {
            localVue,
            vuetify: new Vuetify(),
            propsData: testProps,
        });
    };

    const testProps = {
        labelText: "Test Label",
        fieldLabel: "testLabel",
        toggleLeftText: "No",
        toggleRightText: "Yes",
        toggleValue: toggleState
    };

    let wrapper;

    beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = wrapperFactory(testProps);
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        wrapper.destroy();
    });

    it("should have correct toggle value", () => {
        const vSwitch = wrapper.find(VSwitch);
        expect(vSwitch.vm.value).toBe(toggleState);
    });

    it("should have correct toggle value after click", async () => {
        const vSwitch = wrapper.find(VSwitch);
        await vSwitch.trigger('click');
        expect(vSwitch.vm.value).toBe(!toggleState);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I might be a bit late for answering your question, but this way you should be able to get your `v-switch`.

`const vSwitch = wrapper.find({ name: 'v-switch' });`

and then trigger the event with

`vSwitch.$emit('change', <true or false>);`, depending on what you're testing.

The limit with this approach is that if you have multiple `v-switch`es in your code, you would need to target them with a `data-test-id`, for example like this:

```
<v-switch data-test-id="my-switch-1"> ... </v-switch>;
<v-switch data-test-id="my-switch-2"> ... </v-switch>;
```

and then I defined a helper function on top of my test file, like so:

```
const getSwitchComponent = (wrapper: Wrapper<Vue>, testId: string): Wrapper<Vue> => {
  const switches = wrapper.findAll({ name: 'v-switch' });
  const component = switches.wrappers.find(wrapper =>
    wrapper.contains(`[data-test-id="${testId}"]`),
  );

  if (!component) {
    throw Error(`Element not found: ${testId}`);
  }

  return component;
};
```

which will let you do something like this:

```
const mySwitch1 = getSwitchComponent(wrapper, 'my-switch-1');
const mySwitch2 = getSwitchComponent(wrapper, 'my-switch-2');
```

and trigger the `change` event so:

```
mySwitch1.vm.$emit('change', false);
mySwitch2.vm.$emit('change', true);
```